# Operand type mismatch for idiv

Tags: assembly, x86

I am currently writing a compiler which produces x86-32 code.

However, I have a problem when trying to implement division.

```
idivl %ecx, %ebx
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `idiv'
```

Does anyone know why? The above lines are the only time `idiv` appears in my code.

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't `idiv` a single operand instruction?

Comment: @Mysticial - Yes, it computes `edx:eax / r32` where `edx:eax` is a bitwise concatenation of `edx` and `eax` to form a 64-bit value and `r32` is any 32-bit register or pointer. The result is placed in `eax` and the remainder in `edx`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my reference, `IDIV` divides the 64-bit integer `EDX:EAX` by the provided register's value.

> idiv — Integer Division
>
> The idiv instruction divides the contents of the 64 bit integer EDX:EAX (constructed by viewing EDX as the most significant four bytes
>   and EAX as the least significant four bytes) by the specified operand
>   value. The quotient result of the division is stored into EAX, while
>   the remainder is placed in EDX.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> idiv <reg32>
> idiv <mem>
> ```
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> idiv ebx ; divide the contents of EDX:EAX by the contents of EBX. Place the quotient in EAX and the remainder in EDX.
> idiv DWORD PTR [var] ; divide the contents of EDX:EAS by the 32-bit value stored at memory location var. Place the quotient in EAX
> ```
>
> and the remainder in EDX.

The `idivl` instruction behaves exactly like `idiv`, except `idivl` is a signed division.

See http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

Another great ref: http://ref.x86asm.net/

Comment: This may be of some use to you, it's essentially a laymens terms list of common instructions and what they do: http://programminggroundup.blogspot.com/2007/01/appendix-b-common-x86-instructions.html

Comment: `idiv` is signed division.  `div` is unsigned.  `idivl` is just `idiv` with an explicit operand-size of 32-bit, in AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 3):

idivl only takes one argument. see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic#Arithmetic_instructions).
it divides the contents of EDX:EAX by the contents of the argument