# Assembly "Error: junk" when trying to multiply and divide

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly and trying to figure out how to do basic register functions such as adding, multiplying, and dividing writing a 32 bit x86 program. Currently, I am trying to write a program that computed the output of "(5+4)/(10*3)". After computing this output, I am trying to exit with the result as the status code. My code is currently:

```
.global main

.type   main    @function
main:
 movl $5, %ebx
 movl $4, %ecx
 addl %ebx, %ecx
 movl %ecx, %eax

 movl $10, %ebx
 movl $3, %ecx
 divl %ebx:%ecx
 mull %eax:%ecx
 push %ecx
    call exit
```

I currently am getting the errors of:

```
e2.s: Assembler messages:
e2.s:19: Error: junk `:%ecx' after register
e2.s:20: Error: junk `:%ecx' after register
```

when I try to compile the code with: `gcc -m32 -o e2 e2.s`

I have looked at [Page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856792/gcc-inline-assembly-error-error-junk-esp-after-expression), and [Page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396261/operand-type-mismatch-for-idiv), and the book "Programming From the Ground Up", but I can't quite figure out the issue.

Comment: Um, the Page 2 you linked to had the answer. "idivl only takes one argument."

Answer (score 2):

You should instead look at an instruction set reference. That will tell you that `div` and `mul` only take a single operand, the other operand and the result is implicit.

`div` with a 32 bit operand will always divide the 64 bit quantity formed from `edx` (high 32 bits) and `eax` (low 32 bits). As for the result, the quotient will be in `eax` and the remainder in `edx`.

`mul` with a 32 bit operand will always multiply `eax` producing a 64 bit result in `edx`:`eax` automatically.

Also, your code first performed the division and then the multiply, which is not what your formula says.

Considering the above, you could rewrite your code like:

```
 movl $10, %eax
 movl $3, %edx
 mull %edx       # eax = 10 * 3, edx = 0
 movl %eax, %ecx # ecx = 10 * 3

 movl $5, %eax
 addl $4, %eax   # eax = 5 + 4

 divl %ecx       # eax = (5 + 4) / (10 * 3)
 push %eax
 call exit
```

Note that this is integer division, so the result will be zero. If you change the numbers also remember that the exit code is 8 bit only.